# The mean of the mean of the Xn combinations by n. is the mean of the Xn

Tags: combinations, average, combinatorics

I have X1...X6. I have taken the combinations by two. For each of those sub-samples I have taken the mean, and then the mean of all of those means:

[(X1+X2)/2 + ... +(X5+X6)/2]/15, where 15 is the total number of combinations.

Now the mean of all of those sub-samples is equal to the mean of :
(X1+X2+X3+X4+X5+X6)/6 .

I am asking for some help in order to either PROVE it (as a generalazation), or why this happens? Because even if I increase the combinations for example the combinations of 6 by 3 or 4 etc the results are the same.

Thank you

Comment: This is probably in the wrong place. Should be in the maths exchange site. But it was too tempting to not try and answer it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here's a quick page of scribbles that shows that no matter how many items you have if you take the mean of all combinations of 2 pairs and then take the mean of those means then you will always get the mean of the original sum.

[image]

Explanation...

- I work out what the number of combinations is first. For later use.
- Then it's just a matter of simplifying the calculation.
- Each number is used `n-1` times. X1 is obvious. X2 is used `n-2` times but also used once in the sum with X1. (This bit is a bit harder with `r > 2`)
- At the end I substitute in the actual values for the number of combinations.
- This then cancels out to give the sum of all the numbers over n. Which is the mean.

The next step is to show this for all values `r` but that shouldn't be too hard.

Substituting r instead of 2. I found that each number is used `(n-1) choose (r-1)` times.

But then I'm getting the wrong cancellation out of it.

[image]

I know where I went wrong... I miscalculated the calculation for (n-1)choose(r-1)

With the correct formula the answer falls out to S/n.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I have proved it for when it is by 2. However, I get stuck with the general case when have N and choose by K.

Comment: @HerculesApergis ok, a bit more scribbling. The number of times each number is used for combinations of size K is `(N-1) choose (K-1)`. For `6C2` this becomes `5C1` which is 5 and just happens to be `(N-1)`. The maths are a bit more complicated but you can use the same substitution and the same cancellation process to get to `sum of all numbers over n`. :)

Comment: Like tried for all values of the r that you said. The calculations were beyond my skills. Is there a theorem that could be used?

Comment: @HerculesApergis are you sure it works for larger values? Try 8 with combinations of size 4.

Comment: Will check It out. Will you be in available later on? I checked it for 6C3 it was the same.

Comment: Yep, just leave a comment and I'll check back :D

Comment: Yes, it is the exact same again.

Comment: @HerculesApergis yeah, I tried myself with 7 choose 3. I think my maths might not be right. Giving it another go. Could you find out how many times each number is used for a few different sizes. That would help :)

Comment: I just proved it..thank you..your trick  that you told me really helped! thank you so much!!!

Comment: @HerculesApergis add your proof as an answer then. I need to see where I'm going wrong.

Comment: yes I was about to post it too!!!, I was through the phone not through a PC and it was IMPOSSIBLE to write it down! even post a picture!! thank you!